# "pageok" received from Ngnix instead of forwarding to upstream server

Tags: nginx

I have the simply nginx configuration below. Instead of Nginx forwarding my requests to the upstream server, I get a "pageok" response instead.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot guys.

**Configuration:**

```
server {

    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    listen 443 ssl;

    #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;


     location / {

          proxy_pass http://www.upstreamserver.com;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Response i get: <!-- pageok -->
<!-- managed by puppet -->
<html>
<pre>pageok</pre>
</html>

Comment: This does not look like an nginx issue. This looks like a problem with your upstream service.

Comment: You are actually right! i changed it to a another url for test and it worked...  but if i access the upstream url directly i get a valid page.... but via proxy i get this "pageok" response?  Anyway. I guess the point is that Nginx is okay... its more or less a problem with how the upstream service treats the nginx request